# How to add [disabled]='!f.valid' to submit button using ng-content in angular 4?

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-ngcontent

Have a form component which contains email, password field and submit button is passed through ng-content so that for login Form 'Login' button can be showed and for register form 'Register' button can be showed. Form component template code:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">

  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="email" 
     class="form-control" 
     placeholder="Enter email address"
     name="email"
     ngModel
     >
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type="password" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Enter the password"
       name="password"
       ngModel
       >
  </div>


  <ng-content select="[submitbtn]" ></ng-content>
```

Code of form's parent component:

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <!--For Login-->
            <app-form-content>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" submitbtn>Login</button>
            </app-form-content>
          </div>
           <!--For register-->
          <div class="col-md-6">
             <app-form-content>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!f.valid" submitbtn>Register</button>
             </app-form-content>
          </div>
      </div>
```

After run this code "TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined" error occured. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) `#f` in parent template because its scope is the entire template where it was declared.

In order to access this variable within parent template i would suggest you to declare property inside your form component:

```typescript
@ViewChild('f') f: NgForm;
```

after that you can get this property from parent template reference `#formContent` in your parent template like:

```typescript
<app-form-content #formContent>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!formContent.f.valid"
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8eysx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**